# Can two photons with correlated polarizations pass into a black hole and be emitted as Hawking Radiation with the correlation intact?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-entanglement, event-horizon, hawking-radiation, bells-inequality

In this scenario photons would be emitted before they reach the centre of the black hole and before colliding with matter from a collapsed star.

Comment: What emits the photons? Is the collapsed star the black hole?

Comment: A beam splitter emits the photons from a crystal  and the black hole is made from a collapsed star.

Comment: The photons in HR will not stand in direct (nor indirect) correlation with the photons from the splitter. The photons from the splitter will be somewhere inside the hole and continue to travel to the singularity.

Comment: So the mass of a black hole doesn't include the mass inside the event horizon

Answer (score 0):

Hawking Radiation comes from the curvature of spacetime around the black hole, not from the contents of the black hole. The photons inside the black hole will contribute to the mass, the gravitational pull, and the curvature of space time, but that doesn't mean that they will be emitted in any direct fashion. Effectively, everything inside the black hole is converted into energy which is devoted to bending spacetime. That energy leaches out via Hawking Radiation, but its not the same set of particles.

Also, Hawking Radiation is extremely slow. Time scales for emission will be billions of years, depending on the size of the black hole. Time scale for light to reach the center of the black hole will be comparable to the radius divided by the speed of light.

In addition, the wavelengths which are emitted are those which are comparable to or longer than the diameter of the black hole. For light to "enter" the black hole in the conventional ray-optics sense, its wavelength must be significantly less than the diameter of the black hole.  (Otherwise, what you'll have is diffraction & refraction of light waves, which will almost certainly spoil your entanglement.)  In any case, what comes out will have much lower frequency than what goes in.

So no, an entangled photon pair can't get lucky and escape a black hole before colliding with the matter inside.

Comment: How does the black hole lose mass if it isn't the  mass energy at its centre that is decreasing. What and where is the mass of the hole? I  saw a summary where Hawking said that the particle antiparticle idea wasn't really what caused emission He said that the gravity distorted all fields so much that they were not clearly defined and so their energy was not This meant that some energy could have escaped  But was he talking about the inside or outside of the event horizon

Comment: The mass energy at its center is decreasing, but it is not identifiable as specific pieces of matter that fell in. Everything which enters is indistinguishable. The pair of entangled photons, the star's mass, background radiation, etc. all become "mass-energy".  For someone outside, there are no electrons, neutrons, or entangled pairs of photons inside, just "mass-energy".  When the entangled photons enter, they make it bigger, but they cease to have their own identity. That black-hole "particle" decays by Hawking Radiation, but what comes out is unrelated to the details of what went in.

Comment: Then how does the radiation preserve information if what is emitted doesn't relate to what goes in?

Comment: If I understand https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-black-hole-information-paradox-comes-to-an-end-20201029/ correctly, everything coming out of a black hole is in some sense entangled together: The photons you send in will become entangled with all other future & past Hawking radiation from the hole. Not real clear on that though; it's still open research and parts of it are controversial.